# How to get all files with similiar name asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to get all the files that have similiar names a example
File name:123456789.png

And i have files that follow that name but have a page number after so it would be:
1234567891
1234567892
1234567893

How can i do this?
This is the code where i want to make it happen.

```
protected void ShowPng(string pathPgnImg)
{
    string sImageName = "";
    string sImagePathImages = Server.MapPath("Anexos/");
    string pngFile = "";
    string FileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(pathPgnImg);
    string fileWithoutPathAndExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileWithoutPath);
    DirectoryInfo AnexoDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(PathForPdf);
    FileInfo[] filesInDir = AnexoDirectory.GetFiles("*" + fileWithoutPathAndExt + ".png");
    
    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)            {
        pngFile = foundFile.FullName;
    }

    string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(pngFile);
    m_sImageNameUserUpload = fileWithoutPathAndExt + sFileExt;
    m_sImageNameGenerated = Path.Combine(sImagePathImages, m_sImageNameUserUpload);

    //Literal1.Text += "<img src=" + '"' + pngFile + '"' + "/>";
    imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos\\" + Path.GetFileName(pngFile);

    if (m_sImageNameUserUpload != "")
    {
        pnlCrop.Visible = true;
        imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos/" + m_sImageNameUserUpload;
        Session["ImageName"] = m_sImageNameUserUpload;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to display all of the img files with similiar names or just store all of them in variables to use them after as a carousell or something of the genre.

Comment: Did you try with _fileWithoutPathAndExt + "*.png"_ and remove the first *

Comment: @Steve i will try it right now

Comment: @Steve your awesome works like a charm. Do you want me to make it a answer or can you do it, you do deserve it

Comment: I think that this is just an oversight. Probably the best course is to delete the question, but if you prefer to add an answer then don't wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will return all the files that follow your search pattern

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "1234567??.png");
```

Where `@"c:\"` place your directory search.

About the pattern. The symbol `*` find any length of chars, the symbol `?` finds one char only.

For example the `1234567*` will find anything starts with `1234567`
For example the `1234567??.png` will find anything that have any kind of characters on the `?` points eg `123456789.png`, `123456700.png`, `123456734.png` etc

And you can also make combinations of the * and ? symbols.

More to Read [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_) ,